# What is the difference between a linear functional and a scalar valued function?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

What is the difference between a linear functional and a scalar valued function?

Also, if a functional is supposed to be the function of function (map from a function space to scalar), how does a 'function from vector field to its scalar field' is called a functional? are the vectors in the vector field considered as functions?

Comment: A scalar-valued function is not necessarily linear.

Comment: "a function is supposed to be the function of function" I presume the first "function" should say "functional", i.e. "a functional is supposed to be the function of function". In that case, this is wrong - a functional by no means has to be defined on or takes values in a space of functions.

Comment: Functionals take vectors and return scalars. Scalar-valued functions are usually just called functions (in contrast to mappings or transformations or operators).

Comment: @Bernard Ok..so is a linear scalar-valued function same as a functional? or what is the difference between functional and a scalar-valued function?

Comment: @Panda Scalar valued functions can also take vectors and return scalars. Do scalar-valued functions only take in scalar and return scalar?

Comment: For me functional is just a map from a vector space into its base field. If in addition, it linear, we often use the term `linear form`.

Comment: @ok so what is 'functional'?

Comment: @GRANZER I'm sorry, I forgot to add that a functional is linear.

Comment: @Panda Ok a functional is always linear, while a scalar-valued function may or may not be linear. So is a linear scalar value function the same as a functional?

Comment: Yes, if the function is defined on a vector space. Functionals are precisely the bounded elements of the dual vector space, which are linear transformations taking values in the scalars.

Comment: Quite often, the vector spaces on which we define functionals are spaces where the vectors are functions, for example, $C(S)$, the space of all continuous functions from $S \to \Bbb R$. This might have confused you about what functionals are, particularly since many functionals can be defined by making use of the function properties (for example, for each $s \in S$, you can define the evaluation functional $e_s(f) := f(s)$. But that is not part of the meaning of "functional" itself. It is just an example of one.